# Check if value exists in a multidimensional array java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, contains

Without a `for loop`, is there any way to see if a value exists in a `multidimensional array`? I found

```
 Arrays.asList(*ArrayName*).contains(*itemToFind*)
```

but that will only search the first dimension of the array, and I need to search 2 dimensions.

Comment: What's wrong with using a loop? Even `contains()` uses a loop internally.

Comment: Recursion would work :)

Comment: @zgc7009 better yet, serialize the array as XML and then search for the text. Everything is better with XML :-)

Comment: @Ted, I'm just trying to save myself time if possible

Comment: @zgc, how would I use recursion? I'd have to know if the row contained the value before I knew which row to check, wouldn't I?

Comment: @sJuan, I haven't worked with XML before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a two-dimensional array that contains **5 rows** and **5 columns**. The array is an **int** type and have initialized with a value **i*j**.
Already exists a method that takes a row number and value to search for.

```
private static Integer[][] myarray = new Integer[5][5];

public static boolean exists(int row, int value) {
    if(row >= myarray.length) return false;
    List<Integer> rowvalues = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(myarray).get(row));
    if(rowvalues.contains(value)) return true;
    return exists(row+1, value);
}
```

Comment: @DwB I didn't mean to suggest it was better than a loop, just an alternative.

Comment: It certainly works, even though it doesn't answer the question, but maybe the answer is that its impossible. If I don't see any more feasible alternatives in a few days, I'll select yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can do almost anything with recursion if you care to headache your way through the logic of it. In this case it shouldn't be too hard

```
private boolean checkForValue(int val, int row, int col){
    if(row == numRows && col == numCols) 
        return false;
    else{
        if(values[row][col] == val)
            return true
        else if(col < (numCols - 1))
            checkForValue(val, row, col + 1);
        else
            checkForValue(val, row + 1, 1);
    }
}
```

However, if you are just wanting to save time I think the for loop really is pretty efficient to start

```
private boolean checkForValue(int val){
    for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < numCols; j++){
            if(values[i][j] == val) return true;
        }
    }
    return false; //it will reach here if return true was not called.
}
```

Neither is too rough.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can use Bloom filters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) or create a tree-based index for the keys of your Array, such as a Trie (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Basically you'd need a data structure to look for the values, and not for the keys. It would not cost much space or speed since you could re-use the references of the value objects on both data structures (yours and the one you elect)

Comment: Not sure where to even start for a data structure. Would I use Java Dictionaries?

Comment: Well, think in term of a database. A database doesn't work like an array where the elements are accessed via a positional index. They work with a second data structure ( for example primary keys ) that help find the desired row. What I am suggesting here is, since you don't want to use the positional array, that you can introduce a secondary structure, which would serve as an index for your array. Anyway, your question was "Is it possible?" The answer is "Yes".