# search for an element in a two dimentional array (matrix)

Tags: java

I am using Java to write my code. Somewhere i have a matrix of String type: `String[][] s = {{"a","b"},{"1","1"}}`. I need to see if an specific element exists in that matrix or not. I know that I can use two inners `for` loops to do it. I was wondering if there is inner string method or something like that to do it easier. something like:

`s.contains(a);`

in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069740/check-if-value-exists-in-a-multidimensional-array-java) you should still do it for each row and cannot do it for all matrix at once

Comment: @yash that works for arrays but it seems not working for matrix :|

Comment: @Yvette [here]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069740/check-if-value-exists-in-a-multidimensional-array-java)you should still do it for each row and cannot do it for all matrix at once

Comment: @Tunaki [here]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069740/check-if-value-exists-in-a-multidimensional-array-java)you should still do it for each row and cannot do it for all matrix at once